# Problem with the Network App on Elementary OS

Tags: lenovo

I posted this question in reddit a couple of days ago but I got no answer so far.  So, **with the permission of this community, I'd like to post here the same question**.

Do any of you have had any issue connecting to the internet using the wireless software that comes with the OS? I have to wait for 3 hours for it to work. I can see the wireless available so the network card works (and other Linux OSes too).  but for some reason the network app lingers trying to connect and then it gets disconnected.  I had to install Wicd app from the app store. Now I don't have a problem connecting to the internet.

**From time to time I get lucky and when I reboot** when I am at the log in screen the native EOS network app works and I get connected, but 90% of the time it does not, and I end up using WICD.  **Which works fine, but the APP store does not work at all** :(

Sorry for the essay.  But can someone give me a hand on that?

Thank you in advanced.

As far as I know I was asked in Reddit to post screenshots of my desktop.  I went as far as to fill out a bug report on a txt file.  meaning that the following command were placed inside a file.  Example:
**uname -a > Bugfix.txt, 
dmesg >> Bugfix.txt, 
lsusb -v >> Bugfix.txt**

A link to the tar file is below.

Thank you once again for your support.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cj9LU0RHhda9gEeu2YLsLkZErwv3yoBT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong with this train of thought but I believe there is a problem with the driver for the Atheros loading correctly. Also, if the WLAN has been spotty at best and with the App Store not able to connect you may have missed updates. Missing updates may or may not have something to do with this.

First, at a command line, I would try grabbing all updates and rebooting the machine. Open Terminal and do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot your machine and see if your WiFi (not using WICD) will connect. If not, let's try reloading the driver and restarting the wireless. Again, in Terminal, do the following:

```
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Then:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If your wireless still hasn't started, try one more reboot and see if it is working. Comment back with the results of the above.

Good Luck and hope this helps!!!!

Comment: Hey thank you for answering this problem.  Sadly, it is not working for me.  still have the same problem.  Is there anything I can do better.  obviously I followed the diretion to the letter.  No luck.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to say that all I had to do was reinstalled the OS again.  Now I'd working perfectly.